# What are the basic principles/tenets of semantic web that an architect should know?

Tags: semantics, semantic-web

Core principles and tenets for designing a system. is this really web 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core principles would include understanding of RDF, RDFS, OWL and 
how arbitrary knowledge can be represented using these specs.

Understanding of what reasoners can do with semantic data is essential.
Then comes the idea of intelligent agents.
Then comes understanding of why this is all needed and why it was designed that way.

This would give you the clue about how promising (or not) is this technology.
For the software architect it would be good to know how OWL data can be efficiently stored(in RDBMS or in any other way for example).

As for myself I find this interesting but in reality it is yet very far from the 
point where average users can benefit from it on the regular Web.